# SQL Join two tables with different number of rows get all rows from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I'm trying to join two tables with a different number of rows. Client Number is an identifying field in both tables.

The first table includes the client number for all clients. 
so either could be referenced). To complicate things further, the ClientNumber2 field is a text field but I need it to be a number like the other client number fields. There is also a region field in the second table that I need to limit to certain region numbers.
The second table includes the client number only for clients who meet certain specifications. Some of the clients in the second table have a second client number.

I want to create a new column that shows the client number from the first table for all clients who do not exist in the second table, shows the second client number in the second table if it exists, otherwise, the client number from the first table (which is the same as client number in the first column of the second table

I've included the syntax I'm using below. It runs without errors. The OriginalCN field returns the desired value for those with a value in ClientNumber2 of Table 2 but is returning null values for all others. I cannot figure out how to get it to work correctly. I've also included sample tables and my desired table. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
CLIENT TABLE 1
CLIENT NUMBER
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

CLIENT TABLE 2  
CLIENT NUMBER   2ND CLIENT NUMBER     REGION
2                 14                    1
6                                       2
8                 15                    2

DESIRED RESULT
1
14
3
4
5
6
7
15
```

Here is the syntax I am using:

```
SELECT
TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER
TABLE1.CLIENTNUMBER

CASE
WHEN TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER IS NULL THEN TABLE1.CLIENTNUMBER

WHEN TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER2 IS NULL THEN TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER

WHEN TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER2 = ' ' THEN TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER

ELSE
CAST(TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER2 AS INT)

END AS OriginalCN

FROM DSS.DBO.TABLE1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
RPTO.DBO.TABLE2
ON
DSS.DBO.TABLE1.CLIENTNUMBER = RPTO.DBO.TABLE2.CLIENTNUMBER

WHERE TABLE2.REGION IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Don't use the MySQL tag when asking questions about Sql Server. They are two very different database products.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is completely negating the LEFT OUTER JOIN. If there's no corresponding row in TABLE2 then REGION will be NULL, which isn't `IN (1,2,3)`.

Comment: I thought I was showing region values in the sample tables, but in case that's not showing up I don't think that's the problem. In the actual Table 2 all rows do have a region value (none are null) and there are many in 1,2, and 3.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I apologize. I'm very, very new to SQL programming and language. I did not realize that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(t2.ClientNumber2,' ') As Int), t1.ClientNumber) As ClientNumber
FROM DSS.DBO.TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN RPTO.DBO.TABLE2 t2 ON t1.CLIENTNUMBER = t2.CLIENTNUMBER
WHERE COALESCE(t2.REGION, 1) IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This may be the first time I've ever used the NULLIF() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to reply. This is working with no errors, but still not returning the desired results.

Comment: The only change I made to your suggestion is I added Client Number from Table 1 between Select and Coalesce because I also want that column included. I guess I should have put that in my "Desired Results" table - I want to have two columns - one showing the new Client Number field and one showing Client Number from Table 1. Do you think my addition is what messed it up?

Comment: You need a comma between column names in the select list. If you have that, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
CREATE TABLE #CLIENT_TABLE_1
  (CLIENTNUMBER INT)

INSERT #CLIENT_TABLE_1
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8)


CREATE TABLE #CLIENT_TABLE_2
  (CLIENTNUMBER INT,scNDCLIENTNUMBER varchar(10),REGION INT)

INSERT #CLIENT_TABLE_2
VALUES( 2,'14',1),(6,' ',2),(8,'15',2)

SELECT CASE
         WHEN b.CLIENTNUMBER IS NOT NULL
              AND len(b.scNDCLIENTNUMBER)>0  THEN b.scNDCLIENTNUMBER
         ELSE a.CLIENTNUMBER
       END Result
FROM   #CLIENT_TABLE_1 a
       LEFT JOIN #CLIENT_TABLE_2 b
              ON a.CLIENTNUMBER = b.CLIENTNUMBER
```

**Output :**

```
+------+
|Result|
+------+
| 1    |
| 14   |
| 3    |
| 4    |
| 5    |
| 6    |
| 7    |
| 15   |
+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Will I actually have to enter actual values after the values or just enter the column name?

Comment: I only put 8 sample rows in, but there are thousands of rows in my actual tables so it's not feasible to type all of those in!

Comment: @crisu2 Am not getting what you are trying to say. This is just an example. Replace the temp tables with your original table and check.